# Auth::guest() returns true for both logged in and logged out users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am new to laravel and so I was trying to create a small project for learning purpose. I have used the inbuilt Auth for login and register. These automatically generated pages work so well, now In this I created a route to resource posts by using controller called postcontroller.

Now in the postcontroller  I  check if the user is authorized to return a view: posts else to login page. So to check it I do following

```
if (!Auth::guest())

return view('posts');

else

return "......";
```

Now here the Auth::guest() returns true for both logged in and logged out users.

Comment: does your route have the 'web' middleware applied?

Comment: Yes  Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () { Route::auth(); Route::get('/home's,'homecontroller@index);

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are logged in?

try to dump your Auth::user() data with

`dd(Auth::user());`

And by the way, if you are returning in the if statement you do not need to use else.

Comment: Yes,  even though I am logged in it shows null when I dump Auth::user in my postcontroller

Comment: Well, it should be Auth::user(). But you said it returns null, which means that you are not logged in.

Comment: But I do logged in using the provided login page,

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you use the 'web' middleware. By default, the home page does not use this but the /home route does, which is why the blade templates work under /home.

Add the 'web' middleware and dd(Auth::user()) and you'll see better results.

Answer (score 0):

But You MUST add this line of code for the middleware to know in postcontroller that it needs for check for logged in users.Add this is PostController:

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

After this you need to make sure the routes are added onto the route list. This is done by adding the given line in Routes/web.php

```
Route::resource('user','PostController');
```

recheck if its added by typing the below command in terminal:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Once the route is added, the controllers know they can talk to each other, you are all set.

Note: Except means user can access ONLY index and show routes if user is logged in . Look at laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication) here for more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

if(!Auth::user())

//user not login

else

//user logined

Comment: But I guess the question is regarding Auth::guest()